# How can you delete rows based on date in r?

Tags: r, date, delete-row

I want to delete rows if the dates in between are more than 30 days. Im not sure how to tackle this, so hopefully someone can help me.

My data looks like:

```
Sessionid          Clientid        Date (D-M-Y)         Conversion
   1                  1             01-01-2020             No
   2                  1             02-01-2020             No
   3                  1             03-01-2020             No
   4                  1             15-02-2020             No
   5                  1             16-02-2020             No
   6                  1             17-02-2020             Yes
   7                  2             01-01-2020             No
   8                  2             02-01-2020             Yes
```

So in this example I want to delete the first three rows becauase between session 3 and 4 of client 1 there hasn't been interaction in 30 days. So my output has to look like:

```
Sessionid          Clientid        Date (D-M-Y)         Conversion
   4                  1             15-02-2020             No
   5                  1             16-02-2020             No
   6                  1             17-02-2020             Yes
   7                  2             01-01-2020             No
   8                  2             02-01-2020             Yes
```

So for every conversion I want to check all the prior sessions and for every session if they are in a period of 30 days. So even if a customer has 5 sessions, but between every session are 28 days is fine.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: what should happen when all sessions are 28 days apart? so session 1 is within 30 days of session 2, session 2 within 30 days of 3, etc... should they all be removed except session 3?

Comment: No, if the two sessions are within 30 days they could stay in. I only need to control for the fact that a customer didn't interact in 30 days. So even a client with 5 sessions that all have 28 days difference could stay in

Comment: within 30 days of what? The last session of the client? Becase Sessionid 2 is within 30 days of sessionid 3..

Comment: Yes true, but I want to check it from the point where a customer did a conversion. So in session 6 client converted. Session 5 can stay in because its within 30 days of session 6. Session 4 can stay in because it's within 30 days of session 5. Session 3 has to go because it's not within 30 days of session 4. And because session 3 needs to be deleted, all other prior sessions also need to go (so 1 and 2). Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

One basic strategy is:

1. `split()` the data frame by customer
2. on each data frame, remove the rows that are too far from the conversion date with `lapply()`
3. piece the data frame back together -- I'll use `do.call` with `rbind()`, but there are other possible options

Here's the strategy in action (this is a rewritten version that correctly handles cases where there is more than one conversion per customer, since I didn't know if that was important to you):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Sessionid = 1:13,
  Clientid = c(rep(1, 6), 2, 2, rep(3, 4), 4),
  Date = as.Date(c("01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "15-02-2020",
                   "16-02-2020", "17-02-2020", "01-01-2020", "02-01-2020",
                   "01-05-2020", "15-06-2020", "01-08-2020", "02-08-2020",
                   "02-03-2020"),
                 "%d-%m-%y"),
  Conversion = c(rep("No", 5), "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")
) # expanded toy data set meant to demonstrate cases with multiple / no conversions

df

#    Sessionid Clientid       Date Conversion
# 1          1        1 2020-01-01         No
# 2          2        1 2020-01-02         No
# 3          3        1 2020-01-03         No
# 4          4        1 2020-02-15         No
# 5          5        1 2020-02-16         No
# 6          6        1 2020-02-17        Yes
# 7          7        2 2020-01-01         No
# 8          8        2 2020-01-02        Yes
# 9          9        3 2020-05-01         No
# 10        10        3 2020-06-15        Yes
# 11        11        3 2020-08-01         No
# 12        12        3 2020-08-02        Yes
# 13        13        4 2020-03-02         No


step1 <- split(df, df$Clientid)
# break df into a list of data frames according to Clientid

step2 <- lapply(step1, function(x) {
  daterange <- x[x$Conversion == "Yes", ]$Date
    # record set of successful conversion dates
  daterange <- unlist(lapply(daterange, function(y) seq(y-30, y+30, by = "days")))
    # puff out set of days by 30 days in either direction from each conversion
  x[x$Date %in% daterange, ]
    # subset each data frame by keeping only those with a date in the range
})

df2 <- do.call("rbind", step2)
  # glue the list of data frames back together
row.names(df2) <- NULL
  # remove junk artifact row names

df2

#   Sessionid Clientid       Date Conversion
# 1         4        1 2020-02-15         No
# 2         5        1 2020-02-16         No
# 3         6        1 2020-02-17        Yes
# 4         7        2 2020-01-01         No
# 5         8        2 2020-01-02        Yes
# 6        10        3 2020-06-15        Yes
# 7        11        3 2020-08-01         No
# 8        12        3 2020-08-02        Yes
```